# Getchanges() rest api fetching only 1000 records

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, java-api

I am using sharepoint rest api to fetch all change logs of a sub site using

```
https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXX-Test-SharePoint/_api/web/getchanges
```

But it is fetching only 1000 records 
I want to fetch all records.
i have also tried below url

```
https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXX-Test-SharePoint/_api/web/getchanges?$top=2000&$OrderBy=Time%20desc
```

but its not working 
Any workaround for this